# Truncating old log tables giving error

Tags: database, csv, performance, importexport, server

we bought magento extension for uploading the products through excel sheet.

we are uploading Products using csv file. now uploading speed is too much less.

I am trying this query to increase upload speed of the upload :

```
TRUNCATE log_url; TRUNCATE log_url_info; TRUNCATE log_visitor;
 TRUNCATE log_visitor_info;  TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_import;
 TRUNCATE dataflow_batch_export; TRUNCATE index_event;  
 TRUNCATE report_event;
```

but i am getting this error :

```
#1701 - Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint 
(`database`.`index_process_event`, CONSTRAINT
 `FK_INDEX_PROCESS_EVENT_EVENT_ID_INDEX_EVENT_EVENT_ID` FOREIGN KEY
 (`event_id`) REFERENCES `database`.`index_event` (`event_id`))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution here :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

TRUNCATE table1;
TRUNCATE table2;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

credits : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452760/truncate-foreign-key-constrained-table